# Prometheus Couchbase Exporter container is not working

Tags: go, prometheus, couchbase, exporter

I am trying to run the couchbase exporter(latest version) in docker to get the couchbase metrics in to Prometheus but the container is crashing with the below error logs.

```
{"caller":"log.go:40","date":"2021-08-03T18:43:57.916Z","level":"info","logger":"metrics","message":"Couchbase Address: abc.xyz.com:8091","ts":1628016237.915603}
{"caller":"log.go:40","date":"2021-08-03T18:43:57.917Z","level":"info","logger":"metrics","message":"Starting metrics collection...","ts":1628016237.915603} 
{"caller":"log.go:40","date":"2021-08-03T18:43:57.917Z","level":"info","logger":"metrics","message":"dial CB Server at: http://abc.xyz.com:8091","ts":1628016237.915603} 
{"caller":"log.go:40","date":"2021-08-03T18:43:57.917Z","level":"info","logger":"metrics","message":"Registering Collectors...","ts":1628016237.915603} 
{"caller":"log.go:40","date":"2021-08-03T18:43:57.917Z","level":"info","logger":"metrics","message":"Serving Metrics","ts":1628016237.915603} 
{"caller":"log.go:40","date":"2021-08-03T18:43:57.917Z","level":"info","logger":"metrics","message":"starting server on 127.0.0.1:9091","ts":1628016237.915603} 
{"caller":"log.go:40","date":"2021-08-03T18:44:02.921Z","level":"info","logger":"metrics","message":"Begin collection of Node Stats","ts":1628016237.915603} 
{"caller":"log.go:40","date":"2021-08-03T18:44:02.921Z","level":"info","logger":"metrics","message":"Current Node Cache empty. Retrieving","ts":1628016237.915603} 
{"caller":"log.go:40","date":"2021-08-03T18:44:02.944Z","level":"info","logger":"metrics","message":"Cluster name is: abc","ts":1628016237.915603}
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x30 pc=0x7b4979]
```

The exporter is connecting to couchbase DB but not able to get the metrics due to this error

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x30 pc=0x7b4979]
```

Here are the links to Couchbase exporter code and the image registry.

https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-exporter

https://hub.docker.com/r/couchbase/exporter

I am suspecting that the exporter code is having a bug but I am new to couchbase and GO, so looking for the help here.

Has anyone successfully used the latest version of couchbase exporter (container based) to get the couchbase metrics?

Comment: you have not shown the stack trace.